# Hide TabLayoutPanel or TabPanel header

Tags: gwt

Is there a way hide and show a TabLayoutPanel, so the titles disappear?
I think that I can use CSS and set the property visibility but how to set an id for the titles' tabs without its content?

Answer (score 1):

In fact TabPanel is a combination of TabBar and DeckPanel - try to go this way, you can combine it manually and have a control on both parts.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like a [DeckPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DeckPanel.html) : a TabPanel without the titles

Comment: Thanks for answering. In fact, I'm trying to use a button that hides the titles of the panel so that the widget inside every tab have the maximum height and width